# Is this Comparer class from SSCLI library code ThreadSafe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, sscli

```
public abstract class Comparer<T> : IComparer, IComparer<T>
    {
        static Comparer<T> defaultComparer;    

        public static Comparer<T> Default {
            get {
                Comparer<T> comparer = defaultComparer;
                if (comparer == null) {
                    comparer = CreateComparer();
                    defaultComparer = comparer;
                }
                return comparer;
            }
        }
```

First, is the Default property thread safe?
Isn't it possible that effect of the following statement

```
comparer = CreateComparer();
```

might not be visible to threads other than creating thread?
So, multiple instances of  Comparer are constructed?

Is Microsoft doing this for the sake of trading synchronization cost off with the cost of 
creating multiple objects?

Second why defaultComparer is first assigned to comparer variable first...and then later on swapped?
why do Comparer comparer = defaultComparer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Multiple comparers do indeed get created, defaultComparer gets assigned multiple times.  Not a problem, they are all the same.  The garbage collector takes care of the extras.  And the atomic assignment guarantee that the CLR offers for object references ensures that the static cannot be read incorrectly.

Comment: Ok. but why this dance with, first assigning Comparer<T> comparer = defaultComparer and then swapping later...can't one simplly do if (defaultComparer == null) {defaultComparer = CreateComparer(); return defaultComparer? }

Comment: It takes less machine code bytes to do it this way.  The static, which needs 4 address bytes, is only accessed twice.

Comment: oh you mean that accessing static has less cost than accessing thread local? how so?

Comment: Also, how does .NET memory model play into this?

Comment: It is not thread local, just local.  Use Debug + Windows + Assembly to see this stuff for yourself.

Comment: I meant to say local (thread local was mistyping)..Will look into the assembly

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did compare the assembly code. And the above implementation is more space efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it certainly is possible that multiple instances of the comparer are created. Before you can answer whether or not the `Default` property is thread-safe we should probably define what we *want* to be safe. If you only ever want a single instance to be created then it certainly is not thread-safe. However, if you relax your requirement to allow for multiple instances as long as *some* instance is returned then it certainly does that.

I would say the reasoning behind this decision was based partly on the fact that the `IComparer` instance is stateless. That means from a callers perspective it really does not matter which instance the caller grabs because they all look and operate the same. In other words, it really would not matter if a single thread repeatedly read `Default` and got a different instance each time.